# Django REST framework: How to use multiple PKs in URL with class based views/serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have two models (examples):

```
class Container(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class ObjInContainer(models.Model):
    Container = models.ForeignKey(Container, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

A `Container` can have N number of `ObjInContainer`.

I'm trying to write a REST API to do two things:

First: See all `ObjInContainer` from a single `Container`:

```
# urls.py
url(r'^container/(?P<container_id>\d+)/objects_in_container/$', ContainerObjectsListAPIView.as_view(), name='container_objects_list'),

# views.py
class ContainerObjectsListAPIView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = ObjInContainer.objects.all()
    queryset = queryset.prefetch_related('container')
    serializer_class = ContainerObjectsListAPIView

# serializer.py
class ContainerObjectsListAPIView(ModelSerializer):
    container = SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = ObjInContainer
        fields = [
            'id',
            'container',
        ]
    def get_container(self, obj):
        return str(obj.container.name)
```

But this lists all `ObjInContainer` from ALL `Container`. How do I tell REST Framework that the `Container` it needs to get the `ObjInContainer` from is the one in the URL from `<container_id>` ?

I suppose in `views.py` where I declare `queryset = ObjInContainer.objects.all()`, should really be `queryset = ObjInContainer.objects.filter(container_id=container_id)`, but how do I access the `<container_id>` part of the URL in the view class?

Any my second issue is how to detail a single `ObjInContainer`, by using two different IDs in the URL?

```
# urls.py
url(r'^container/(?P<container_id>\d+)/objects_in_container/(?P<obj_in_container_id>\d+)/$', ContainerObjDetailAPIView.as_view(), name='container_object_detail'),

# views.py
class ContainerObjDetailAPIView(RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = ObjInContainer.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ContainerObjDetailSerializer

# serializer.py
class ContainerObjDetailSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    container = SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = ObjInContainer
        fields = [
            'id',
            'container',
        ]
    def get_container(self, obj):
        return str(obj.container.name)
```

So if I go to URL `container/2/objects_in_container/55/`, how do I tell the REST Framework that the first ID (`container_id=2`) is for the `Container` instance, and the second ID (`obj_in_container_id=55`) is for the `ObjInContainer` instance?

I suppose both issues really boil down to, how does Django figure out RegEx from the URL, and where exactly are those filtered out and applied to the models in the DB?

Comment: Are you providing users a list of containers to select before they can see the list ofobjInContainer that belongs to the selected container?

Comment: And I think it should be `selected_related` instead of `prefetch_related` when you try to fetch `Container` from `OjbInContainer`

Comment: Yes, I have a way for users to see all `Container` objects, and their IDs and so on. From there they can use one of those IDs to change the URL through whatever means they want to `mysite.com/api/container/<id>`.

And yeah, it was `select_related`

Answer (score 0):

**Answer to you first question:**
assuming you want to show the list of `ObjInContainer` when they click into the corresponding `Container` URL, you can use the `Container` id in the URL to filter the `ObjInContainer` view`:

```
class ContainerObjectsListAPIView(ListAPIView):
serializer_class = ContainerObjectsSerializer #I assume you have a typo in your code

def get_queryset(self):
    id= self.kwargs['id']
    return ObjInContainer.objects.filter(container__id=id)
```

**Answer to your second question:**
Why would you need two ids to get one object? The `ObjInContainer` id alone is sufficient.